# Fetching Multiple Firestore Documents for RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch multiple documents from my Firestore collection so I can populate my RecyclerView. However, I'm getting a mismatch error when I try to hook my `categories` ArrayList to the QuerySnapshot, it says it's looking for `kotlin.collections.ArrayList<Category>` but it found `Category?`. What can I do to make my RecyclerView populate my category collection in Firestore? Do I need to rewrite my `val categories = ArrayList<Category>()`? Thank you!

**Category Collection**

[image]

**Category.kt**

```
data class Category(var category: String?, val categoryImage: String?) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString()
    ) {
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(category)
        parcel.writeString(categoryImage)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Category> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Category {
            return Category(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Category?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }

}
```

**CategoryAdapter.kt**

```
class CategoryAdapter(val category: ArrayList<Category>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var selectedCategory = Category("", "")

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindCategory(category[position])

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { v ->
            val context: Context = v.context
            val intent = Intent(context, CategoryServiceActivity::class.java)
            selectedCategory.category = category[position].category
            intent.putExtra("category", selectedCategory)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return category.count()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.categoryrecyclyerview, parent, false)
        return  ViewHolder(view)
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val categoryName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.categoryJobNameTextView)
        val categoryImage = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.categoryImageView)

        fun bindCategory(category: Category) {
            categoryName?.text = category.category
            Picasso.get().load(category.categoryImage).into(categoryImage)
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeFragment.kt**

```
val categories = ArrayList<Category>()
val categoriesDatabaseRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(REF_JOB_CATEGORIES)

categoriesDatabaseRef.orderBy("category").get().addOnSuccessListener(object: OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot> {
     override fun onSuccess(p0: QuerySnapshot?) {
         if (p0 != null) {
            for (querySnapshot in p0.documents) {
                categories = querySnapshot.toObject(Category::class.java)
            }
         }
     }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in your code, the `categories` object is an `ArrayList`. So when you're using the following line of code:

```
categories = querySnapshot.toObject(Category::class.java)
```

It means that you're trying to convert the `querySnapshot` object, which is actually a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) object, into an object of type `Category`, which works perfectly fine. However, you cannot assign that value to the `categories` object because between the `ArrayList` and `Category` classes, there is no inheritance relationship, hence that error.

So there are two ways in which you can solve this. The first solution would be to add an object of type `Category`, at each iteration of the for loop to the list:

```
categoriesDatabaseRef.orderBy("category").get().addOnSuccessListener(object: OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot> {
     override fun onSuccess(p0: QuerySnapshot?) {
         if (p0 != null) {
            for (querySnapshot in p0.documents) {
                val category = querySnapshot.toObject(Category::class.java)
                categories.add(category) //Add the object to the list.
            }
         }
     }
})
```

The second solution, which is even simpler in my opinion, would be to convert the `querySnapshot` directly into a list, by removing the for loop like this:

```
categoriesDatabaseRef.orderBy("category").get().addOnSuccessListener(object: OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot> {
     override fun onSuccess(p0: QuerySnapshot?) {
         if (p0 != null) {
            categories = p0.toObjects(Category::class.java)
         }
     }
})
```

Please see that I have used [toObjects(Class clazz)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot#toObjects(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) method which:

> Returns the contents of the documents in the QuerySnapshot, converted to the provided class, as a list.

So it's `toObjects`, see the `s`? And **not** `toObject`.

Besides that, don't forget that Firebase API is asynchronous. So you cannot simply use the value of `categories` outside the `onSuccess()` method. If you're new to asynchronous programming, I recommend you read the following resource:

- [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953)